# Blender Python Add-on issue

Tags: python, add-on

Im manage to make a simple script to generate a stair in python.
Now I would like to add it as a new mesh, and being able to have a menu where I can modify the value instead of changing the code.
I start from the template addon_addObject

I can recreate my stairs but stuck with creating the parameters. Here is the code.
Thank you for any help

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import (FloatVectorProperty, FloatProperty, IntProperty)
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector


def add_object(self, context):

    #step variable
    cubsize = 2
    posx = 0
    posy = 5
    posz = 2

    scalx = 10
    scaly = 5
    scalz = 0.5

    #step numbers
    step = 20

    #step generators
    for i in range (step):
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=cubsize, location=(posx, cubsize*i+posy*i,cubsize*i+posz*i))
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(scalx, scaly, scalz))

    bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube*")
    bpy.ops.object.join()
    bpy.context.object.name = "G_stair"



class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "parameter stair"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}

    step: IntProperty(
        name="step",
        default=10,
        subtype='TRANSLATION',
        description="scaling",
    )

    def execute(self, context):
        add_object(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'}



# Registration

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="stair",
        icon='PLUGIN')




def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
'''
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`TRANSLATION` is Not a subtype of an int property**

when the code is run you will be getting messages to the system console that

```
TypeError: IntProperty(subtype='TRANSLATION'): subtype not found in ('PIXEL', 'UNSIGNED', 'PERCENTAGE', 'FACTOR', 'ANGLE', 'TIME', 'DISTANCE', 'NONE')
ValueError: bpy_struct "MESH_OT_add_object" registration error: step could not register
```

recommend `subtype = 'DISTANCE'`

No error now, but.. it will have no dimension unit

[image]

If instead we change to a floatproperty

```
step: FloattProperty(
    name="step",
    default=10,
    subtype='DISTANCE',
    description="scaling",
)
```

[image]

Why??

If we look at the `FloatProperty` will see that it has a `unit` setting which `Intproperty` does not.

```
:arg unit: Enumerator in ['NONE', 'LENGTH', 'AREA', 'VOLUME', 'ROTATION', 'TIME', 'VELOCITY', 'ACCELERATION', 'MASS', 'CAMERA', 'POWER'].
:type unit: string
```

Hence the same result is achieved using

```
step: FloatProperty(
    name="step",
    default=10,
    unit='LENGTH',
    description="scaling",
)
```

Note in this case, `step` is a unit-less `int` with minimum 0.  *ie* make sure your translation props are floats.

To get step in your method it will be

```
self.step
```

For example

```
#step generators
for i in range (self.step):
    ...
```

The `AddObjectHelper` class writes its gear first see [How to link the adjust last operation menu to object? Blender 2.80 - 2.81](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160946/how-to-link-the-adjust-last-operation-menu-to-object-blender-2-80-2-81)

[Python performance with Blender operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators)

Will find if you try and create a huge staircase calling `2 * (step + 1)` operators may slow this down considerably.

Another way to do this would be to add an array modifier with both x and z offset, and the choice to apply or not

[Copying an object with python without actually creating a new object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61094/copying-an-object-with-python-without-actually-creating-a-new-object/61254?r=SearchResults&s=1|84.8494#61254)

[image]

**Putting it together**

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import (FloatVectorProperty, 
                       FloatProperty,
                       BoolProperty, 
                       IntProperty)
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper
from mathutils import Matrix

def steps(context, count, size, scale, offset, align, location, rotation, apply_modifier):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
            size=size,
            align=align, 
            location=location, 
            rotation=rotation
            )
    obj = context.active_object
    obj.data.transform(Matrix.Diagonal(scale).to_4x4())
    # add two array modifiers

    arrays = {"x": offset,}

    for axis, displace in arrays.items():          
        mod = obj.modifiers.new(axis, 'ARRAY')
        mod.use_relative_offset = False
        mod.use_constant_offset = True
        mod.count = count
        mod.constant_offset_displace = displace
        if apply_modifier:
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=mod.name)


class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "parameter stair"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO', 'PRESET'}


    size : FloatProperty(
        name="Size",
        default=2,
        unit='LENGTH',
        )

    count: IntProperty(
        name="Steps",
        default=10,
        description="Number of Steps",
        min=0,
    )

    scale : FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Scale",
        default=(1, 1, 1),
        )

    offset : FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Offset",
        subtype='TRANSLATION',
        default=(0, 1, 1),
        )

    apply_modifier : BoolProperty(
        name="Apply Array Modifier",
        default=True,
        )

    def execute(self, context):
        steps(
            context,
            self.count,
            self.size,
            self.scale,
            self.offset,
            self.align,
            self.location,
            self.rotation,
            self.apply_modifier,
            )

        return {'FINISHED'}



# Registration

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="stair",
        icon='PLUGIN')




def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Thank you @batFINGER Using Array was the solution I think about. But if I would like to use a panel where I can manage all variables of the stairs, for this exemple is the number of steps, so I should make the loop with self.step after step: FloaProperty